# How to get a second field in query_set?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called 'Report', the model has two fields 'area' connected with ForeignKey to another model called 'Area' and 'country' connected with ForeignKey to another model called 'Country'.

Also I have a dropdown button, for the 'area' field and it supposed to take me to a page where the list of countries belong to the area supposed to show up from the 'country' field.

My model **str** returns 'area' field. Because **str** return 'area' field my 'country' page also showing list of areas instead of list of countries.

I tried `'return '{} {}'.format(self.area, self.country)`. When I do that my 'area' dropdown shows both area and country. Example `'NORTH AMERICA CANADA'`.

So tired to get 'country' field in a different way. `country = Report.objects.filter(country=country)`. But I get error `country is not defined`.

My models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    church_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    water_baptism = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    holy_ghost = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.area

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:report_view')
```

my views.py

def report_list for 'areas' dropdown button

```
@login_required
def report_list(request):
    areas = Report.objects.all()

    context = {
        'areas':areas,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/report_list.html', context)
```

def report_countries for 'countries' dropdown button

```
def report_countries(request, pk):
    countries = Report.objects.all(country=country).filter(id=pk)

    context = {
        'countries':countries
    }
    return render(request, 'users/report_countries.html', context)
```

My report_list.html

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" style="width: 238px;" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    {% for area in areas %}
      <a href="{% url 'users:report_countries' area.pk %}">{{area}}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

my report_countries.html

```
  {% for country in countries %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'users:report_view' country.pk %}">{{country}}</a></p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

</div>
```

I expect: When dropdown 'area' clicked it should take to the list of countries that belong to that area.

Comment: From your post, it seems that countries belong to areas. You should therefore only have `country` in your `Report` model, and `Country` should have a `ForeignKey` to `Area`. Having the correct hierarchy with no redundant foreign keys will help you with selecting countries that belong to an area.

Comment: You code will not work at all, at least the way you're showing it to us. Your `country=country` in your `report_countries()` breaks it. Show us the real code, and show the other models.